# What the difference between Android String.compareTo() and sqlite3_stricmp()?

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, comparison

Is the result of Collections.sort(List) will be the same as SQLite.execute("SELECT text ... ORDER BY text ASC") on any sets of strings?  (https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stricmp.html)

I'm expecting that not.

The next question is - how to get the same result? Without own implementation of  sqlite3_stricmp() in Android.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's default [collations](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) do not know about Unicode.

Android adds [collations LOCALIZED and UNICODE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html), which should use Java's rules.